# jQuery - Select All inputs and Bind Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the most efficient way to select all input elements on a form and then attach a function to each which fires on focus out?

I am thinking along the lines of

```
var allInputs = $("form").each(function(){
    $(this).find(':input').focusout(focusOutFunction);
});

var focusOutFunction = function() { 
 // do focus out things here
};
```

but not quite there yet.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about just:

```
$("form :input").blur(function() { });
```

Comment: That selector will attach an event for each input? Or just one event on the form and will catch the inputs blur?

Comment: @nikoskip -- Actually not too sure - I assume an event for each child `input` of the `form`

Comment: Is it possible to pass in a second select option? i.e on a dropdown or some such?

Comment: @tymeJVI I'm not either, and I'm too lazy to test it for now, hahaha. So a good implementation would be: `$('form').on('blur', 'input', function () { });`

Comment: @user2085143 -- Yes, you can do: `$("form :input, form select")`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use [event bubbling](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing) and [delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) to catch the event on the `input`s common container?

eg:

```
$('div.container').on('blur', function (e) {
    console.log('I haz blurrd: ', e.target);
});
```